# BeginCollectionItem new element not working with jQuery MVC 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to test whether content is in a text field, this works with initially loaded elements, but not the elements (which share the same class name) added using beginCollectionItem.

For example a textbox is added through bci and gets filled in, when filled in and focus goes elsewhere, the textbox will be given the 'makeitred' class.

What's wrong with the javascript I'm using?

**partial using BCI**

```
<div class="editorRow">
    @using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("ispDetails"))
    {
        <div class="ui-grid-c ui-responsive">
            <div class="ui-block-a">
                <span>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.type, new { @class = "isitempty" })
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

**Index segment calling partial** - on page load elements the jQuery works, anything there after using the add button doesn't

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
            {
                <div id="editorRowsEQM">
                    @foreach (var item in Model.ispDetails)
                    {
                        @Html.Partial("EquipView", item)
                    }
                </div>
                @Html.ActionLink("Add", "ispManager", null, new { id = "addItemEQM", @class = "button" });
            }
```

**JS from the Index**

```
$(function () {

$('#addItemEQM').on('click', function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("ispManager")',
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (html) { $("#editorRowsEQM").append(html); }
                });
                return false;
            });
            $(document).on('change', '.isitempty', function checkFill (e) {
                if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
                    $(this).removeClass('makeitred');
                } else $(this).addClass('makeitred');
            });
});
```

Comment: You have not shown your script that adds new items. And you need to remove the `@onchange = "checkFill();` from the textbox - your already handling it with the `$(document).on('change', '.isitempty', function()`

Comment: Added the `onChange` to see if I could get it to catch, have added bci handling code.

Comment: Not clear what your problem is. Are you saying that clicking the 'add' link does not add new items, or that they are added, but the script to change the class does not work for the new items?

Comment: Apologies I'll update - the issue is that the CSS class 'makeitred' is not being added to fields which have been added and contain content.

Comment: But your 'add' script is only adding new items. It does not check if the new added control has content (and the other script only does that when the content is changed. You need to add a check in the 'add' function once you update the DOM

Comment: Not sure if I'm understanding you, so textboxes are being added through bci and they can be filled in, when these are filled in and focus goes elsewhere, the textbox will be given the 'makeitred' class.

Comment: Change you script to `$('#editorRowsEQM').on('change', '.isitempty', function() { ... });` - use the closest ancestor containing the elements rather `document` (more efficient) and remove the `checkFill (e)` bit.

Comment: Nice one - works, chuck in a answer and I'll accept, originally was trying to get it to work across lots of different named rows but I can live with similar code, thanks!

Comment: Changing `document` to `'#editorRowsEQM'` was just a suggestion because its more efficient, but it would not make any difference to your event handling. If this is now working I suspect it's because of the `checkFill (e)`, but then that does not make sense because it would not have worked with the existing items either (which you claim it did).

Comment: The changes you suggested worked, perhaps eliminating a typo I'd not seen, however it was working for the first render row (possibly because of the initial `onChange`) so a typo would be unlikely, either way, it works now, so thank you.